# Change date format of "x hours ago" tool tip?

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, dates, internationalization

Currently it's in the format..

```
MM/DD/YYYY
```

..which confuses me. It's also ambiguous (for 12 days a month anyway), and inconsistent with other parts of the site, such as the Recent page: "Showing 2009-07-05 to 2009-07-05"

Could it be changed to the ISO 8601 (international standard) format?

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

Comment: What about "sep 13 '09 at 5:19 "? (as in "asked ...."). This should also be ISO8601. That's the standard.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am in favor in the ISO 8601 standard due that it follows a setup where a date is numerically larger than a date it it's past.

```
2010-07-05 (1 year from now)
2009-07-05 (today)
2009-06-05 (1 month ago)

20100705 > 20090705 > 20090605
```

And it's very logical to read a date where you go from the largest entity to the smallest.

```
2009-07-05 09:00:00
```

Answer (score 10):

Eh... You've got the whole tooltip, why go with such a brief date format?

> On Sunday the fifth of July, at one second, thirty-six minutes past five o'clock post-meridiem coordinated universal time, in the year of Our Lord two thousand and nine...

Comment: Or we could use Roman Numerals: MMIX-VII-V

Comment: @jrcs3: I would hunt you down and kill you! :-)

Comment: He's not **my** lord. :P