# Change the timestamp format

Tags: feature-request, javascript

Please change the time stamp format for all the comments, answers, and anything else which has a time stamp to one which is parsable in Javascript.  I used to use the TimeStamp Converter script in Greasemonkey, but just recently it has been broken.  It seems as though the format has changed.

The script uses the title of the time stamp span to display the absolute (rather than relative) date that the question / answer / comment was posted.  (not sure anymore where I found the script)  However, Javascript can't parse this date format without lots of extra work - previously, the script worked with

```
var timeStampe = new Date(elm.title);
```

where `elm` is all the elements that have the class `relativetime` or `comment-date`.  Currently the format of the time stamp is `2009-07-20 22:15:20Z UTC`, but Javascript prefers time in the form `Mon, 20 Jul 2009 23:10:47 GMT`.

I am fairly sure that it will be easier (and less browser intensive) to change the date format on the server side rather than the client side, so please consider this request for all those who use Greasemonkey!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's ISO 8601 - and [was just recently changed to that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2560/change-date-format-of-x-hours-ago-tool-tip)!

If you need help parsing this in JavaScript, [try SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436374/how-can-i-convert-datetime-microformat-to-local-time-in-javascript/436562#436562)...

Comment: Okay, thanks for that link.  Do you know of anywhere that the dev team posts a list of the changes that they make to the page structure? I have noticed that there have been other minor changes made as well, but these don't seem to get publicised anywhere!

Comment: I'm not aware of any public changelog here, sorry. You can read the blog, and Jeff's activity history... that'll help, sometimes.