# Bug: make bounty tooltip date formats consistent with the rest

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, date-format

I just noticed this. Hover over a bounty end period and you get:

[bounty date format http://img188.imageshack.us/img188/937/bountydate.png](http://img188.imageshack.us/img188/937/bountydate.png)

but normally it's:

[normal date format http://img181.imageshack.us/img181/1780/normaldate.png](http://img181.imageshack.us/img181/1780/normaldate.png)

I'm sure it's just a minor oversight and a really simple fix.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed; the M/D/YYYY format here is ambiguous with the D/M/YYYY format that is common outside the US.  The ISO 8601 YYYY-MM-DD date format should be used.  It looks like this one was missed as part of [this fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2560/change-date-format-of-x-hours-ago-tool-tip).